# Drag and Drop QWidget into Maya

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, maya

I have a library with textures assets etc in a QListWidget. I would like to enable drag and drop of the widgets into a QApplication, in my case Maya. 
How do I connect the dropEvent with Maya so maya registers that something has been dropped?
Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: I'm not sure to clearly understand your question. Where do you want to activate the drop event? On your QListWidget or on Maya's main window? Do you want to drag the texture thumbnails from your QListWidget and drop them in Maya's viewport?

Comment: Yes, I have a library window with lots of listWidgetItems (thumbnails of hdrs etc etc). 
I want to drag and drop them onto mayas window, which then should register a drop. And I can run a function. 
The plan is to drop and IES light profile, or and HDR light texture into maya which then creates a light with proper connections etc.

Answer (score 0):

With some serious trial and error I found a solution which is actually quite straight forward, as its mostly the case...
So the main thing is to register the event with the main app in my case maya.

```
main_win = mhelper.getQMayaMainWindow()
main_win.installEventFilter(drop_filter)
```

and then in the event filter I need to check which event is being called:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        self.obj = obj      

        if event.type() is event.DragEnter:
            self.mouse_button = QtGui.QApplication.mouseButtons()
            event.accept()

        if event.type() is event.Drop:
            library_w = event.source()
            if self.mouse_button == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:

        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can correctly handle drop event on your maya main window, but one thing is sure, you can do it on every [QtWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html). In my case, I did it on my  qt main window.

```
class Droper(QtGui.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(Droper, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True) # Very important



    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        """
        The event called when the user drag elements over the drop place
        """
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
            print "We don't want this !"


    def dropEvent(self, event):
        """
        The event called when the user drops its elements
        Only if dragEnterEvent accept the event
        """
        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            print url
```

You need to enable acceptDrops on your widget, you can directly do it in its properties in Qt Designer. You also need to define events you want to use, go see [QWidget.dragEnterEvent](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#dragEnterEvent) to see the 4 drag and drop events.

Hope it helped you, ask if you don't understand how to implement it.